# Trouble deploying my webapp to Tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, tomcat7

This is my first effort deploying my own App to a remote tomcat server. I've searched and searched my problem and can't find a solution.

I created a Maven project in eclipse with the `webapp` archetype. My local tomcat installation is listening on `port 8080`, but I have the tomcat installation on my server listening on `port 80'. I've completed and tested my app in Eclipse with Maven and Tomcat, and it works just fine.

I exported my project to a `.war` file and renamed it `ROOT.war`. Then, with the server stopped, I uploaded it into `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`. Then I started the server and the `.war` file autodeployed into the `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT`. When I navigated to `www.myDomain.com` I got a "link seems to be broken" error from Chrome, and a 404 status code.

I checked the logs and got this:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war
Sep 22, 2013 6:31:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig init
SEVERE: Exception fixing docBase for context []
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:87)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:66)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:86)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:363)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Sep 22, 2013 6:31:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file
```

I tried re-creating the `.war` file and trying again, but with no luck. I read some articles explaining that this may be due to a corrupted war file (even though the file structure showed up on my server in full after restarting), so I decided to skip creating a `.war` file completely. I created a copy of `myWebappProject` that I called `ROOT`. Then I just uploaded the `ROOT` directory in my workspace directly to `.../webapps/ROOT`.

After starting the server and navigating to `www.myDomain.com` and `www.myDomain.com/ROOT` and `www.myDomain.com/index.jsp` etcetera etcetera I got the stock error message from Tomcat reading `The requested resource (/ROOT/) is not available.` and variations thereof. There were no exceptions in the log files that provided useful feedback.

The directory structure that I'm using is the default for a Maven project with the webapp archetype.

Thanks in advance for your help. Let me know if there is any other code or log files I can post.

**EDIT**
per @Aaron's recommendation, I tried unzipping the warfile myself and running again. More issues this time:

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 22, 2013 8:35:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component         [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: uploadServlet/Uploader : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class uploadServlet.Uploader)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2840)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
```

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone for the help so far.
I downgraded to Java 1.6 on my development machine as my server is running Java 1.6.0_24. I also used Maven to create the `.war` file via `mvn package`. I'm still getting a 404 and the 'broken link' error from Chrome. Here is the server start-up log.

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war
Sep 22, 2013 9:45:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-3.0-alpha-    1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:    javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 22, 2013 9:45:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: uploadServlet/Uploader : Unsupported     major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class uploadServlet.Uploader)
    at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2840)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2840)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at  org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSe t.java:108)
    at  org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java: 58)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at  org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
Sep 22, 2013 9:45:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component    [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Sep 22, 2013 9:45:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOTBackup
Sep 22, 2013 9:46:30 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took  [36,729] milliseconds.
Sep 22, 2013 9:46:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Sep 22, 2013 9:46:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 37873 ms
```

Comment: Does it work if you deploy the exploded war? I.e. unzip it and copy it into web apps.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few days ago. It worked for me after I deleted all of mavesn cached dependencies (`~/.m2/repository`) and build it again.

Comment: "I've completed and tested my app in Eclipse with Maven and Tomcat, and it works just fine. I exported my project to a .war file and renamed it ROOT.war" try to first create a .war and test that locally. Does that work? I suspect you have an issue there, since if you use maven, you should create .war with that, and not use any .war export of eclipse.

Comment: @kapep "...and build it again." Can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: @eis That makes sense, as it looks like Tomcat is having trouble finding classes that were brought in with maven. I will look into creating a .war with Maven.

Comment: @barkbark I use the [maven war plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and the command `mvn compile war:war`.

Comment: Offending lines seem to be this `INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-3.0-alpha-    1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:    javax/servlet/Servlet.class
` and this `Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: uploadServlet/Uploader : Unsupported     major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class uploadServlet.Uploader)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your stacktrace, I see two things;

1. the *servlet api* is included in your war-file. This is not allowed (by servlet spec), but it shouldn't prevent the app from starting. Try changing the `<scope>` to `provided` for your servlet dependency in your `pom.xml`
2. *Minor / major version is wrong*. This usually means that you have compiled for a newer Java version locally than what you have on your server. (e.g. compiling Java 7 locally and running Java 6 on the server). Try setting the source and target to the Java version you are running on the server in you `pom.xml` (`maven-compiler-plugin`)

Comment: Your second point was my problem. Thanks for the help. I had to change my JDK version for my project to Java 6 on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Unsupported major minor version is one of the errors you building with one version of Java and deploying with another.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your java version installed in your tomcat server. if you server has jdk 1.7 and webapp is developed with jdk1.8 then it will give this kind of error.
2. If point one is proper for you and still getting issue. check your dependencies in pom.xml. if you have incompatible dependency versions. then this error occurs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jsKGhXmm4c